# JavaScript/jQuery - Uncaught TypeError - yet variables have been initiated in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site a user can choose a 'view' for the transcription of medieval documents. For example, at http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/doc/MS609-0001 a user can view the latin in 'interpretive' or 'diplomatic' edition. This is a toggle that uses some script to show/hide spans based on class:

[image]

The problem is that new users are reporting that this doesn't work. The error is:

```
 MS609-0001.xml:506 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
  'latinview' of undefined
  at changeDocView (MS609-0001.xml:506)
  at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (MS609-0001.xml:62)
  changeDocView @ MS609-0001.xml:506
  onclick @ MS609-0001.xml:62
```

As far as I understand, this is likely due to an undefined variable, in this case "state". Similar happens with "Cookies":

```
jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined
 at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (MS609-0001.xml:449)
 at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
 at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)
```

But both are declared and given values in the script:

```
 var state = {
    lang: Cookies.get('deheresi_lang') ? Cookies.get('deheresi_lang') : "en",
    latinview: "inter"
    }
```

So I don't understand why these would be "undefined"?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies is undefined so when you call Cookies.get you got an error.
The cause is this two js files(the second one is what defines Cookies) that are using localhost instead of 'http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr' so you are not loading Cookies:

```
  <script src="http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/resources/js/imageviewer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/resources/js/cookies.min.js"></script>
```

Use the server address:

```
  <script src="http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/resources/js/imageviewer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr:8081/exist/apps/deheresi/resources/js/cookies.min.js"></script>
```